# Asterisk error: Failed to authenticate on INVITE to - can't call

Tags: asterisk, sip

I've installed Asterisk from the ViciBox iso (ViciBox_v.7.x86_64-7.0.4).
I'm using a softphone (BRIA by CounterPath) and I set it up on asterisk by vicidial.
I can correctly receive calls on the Bria soft phone calling the voip number. 
The problem is that I can't make calls.

When I try to call in the asterisk console I have:

```
[May 31 14:19:56] Connected to Asterisk 11.25.1-vici currently running on vicibox7 (pid = 1476)
[May 31 14:20:01]   == Manager 'sendcron' logged on from 127.0.0.1
[May 31 14:20:01]   == Manager 'sendcron' logged off from 127.0.0.1
[May 31 14:20:01]   == Manager 'sendcron' logged on from 127.0.0.1
[May 31 14:20:01]   == Manager 'sendcron' logged off from 127.0.0.1
[May 31 14:20:06]   == Manager 'sendcron' logged on from 127.0.0.1
[May 31 14:20:06]   == Manager 'sendcron' logged off from 127.0.0.1
[May 31 14:20:28]   == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
[May 31 14:20:28]     -- Executing [0039**********@default:1] Goto("SIP/001-00000000", "to-Gloobobusiness,s,1") in new stack
[May 31 14:20:28]     -- Goto (to-Gloobobusiness,s,1)
[May 31 14:20:28]     -- Executing [s@to-Gloobobusiness:1] NoOp("SIP/001-00000000", "Chiamata in uscita sul trunk di gloonobusiness") in new stack
[May 31 14:20:28]     -- Executing [s@to-Gloobobusiness:2] Dial("SIP/001-00000000", "SIP/s@Trunk_Gloobobusiness") in new stack
[May 31 14:20:28]   == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
[May 31 14:20:28]     -- Called SIP/s@Trunk_Gloobobusiness
[May 31 14:20:28] NOTICE[1558][C-00000000]: chan_sip.c:23309 handle_response_invite: Failed to authenticate on INVITE to '"cccenter" <sip:001@79.47.20.72>;tag=as6d2f2341'
[May 31 14:20:28]     -- SIP/Trunk_Gloobobusiness-00000001 is circuit-busy
[May 31 14:20:28]   == Everyone is busy/congested at this time (1:0/1/0)
[May 31 14:20:28]     -- Auto fallthrough, channel 'SIP/001-00000000' status is 'CONGESTION'
```

My dialplan:

```
exten => _+39.,1,Goto(to-Gloobobusiness,s,1)
exten => _39.,1,Goto(to-Gloobobusiness,s,1)
exten => _0039.,1,Goto(to-Gloobobusiness,s,1)

[to-Gloobobusiness]
exten => s,1,NoOp(Chiamata in uscita sul trunk di gloonobusiness)
same => n,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN}@Trunk_Gloobobusiness)

[from-Gloobobusiness]
exten => s,1,NoOp(Chiamata in ingresso mando al 001)
same => n,Dial(SIP/001)
```

Answer (score -1):

What is not clear for you in your debug output? You are trying to call ti

```
s@Trunk_Gloobobusiness
```

Not think any trunk happy with number s.

Comment: if you look at sip debug, you can see: `To: <sip:0039**********@192.168.1.4>`

Comment: That is number you called from softphone. However number dialled to trunk is s. Your dialplan is wrong.

Comment: I've added my dialplan in the post, can you tell me what's wrong? And sorry :)

Comment: Whit some edit I obtained: `Called SIP/0039**********@Trunk_Gloobobusiness` but the error is the same, why??

Comment: I think you just need correct system setup, ask your system administrator do it.

Comment: Yes I know, but there is no admin...I'm the admin that is trying to install the asterisk and vicidial. If you can help me to find the error I'll be really happy. Otherwise if you can put me in the right way to find and solve the problem. Thank's